# Redirecting from asp.net webpage to Silverlight page

Tags: asp.net, silverlight

Within one solution called online exam i've two web projects one using asp.net other using silver light. Now in asp.net page in the the button click event if i give response.redirect to the page in silverlight project it says file not found.

protected void btnTakePicture_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Redirect("http://localhost:2861/ImageCaptureSR.Web/ImageCaptureSRTestPage.aspx");
    }

Am i missing something ??
I added silver light project by adding existing website option

Comment: Can you see the `http://localhost:2861/ImageCaptureSR.Web/ImageCaptureSRTestPage.aspx` page navigating to it using the browser?

Answer (score 0):

The URL (namely the port) appears to be served by the MSVS integrated ASP.NET server. If it really is and your solution consists of two independent projects, I think that the link is broken because the Silverlight project is not running. You can launch two instances of MSVS and start both projects in either of them. Then you can point your browser to either application and the URL will work.

Alternatively, you could install IIS and deploy both projects there. Then you would need no MSVS server and you could run your applications anytime. You would attach the debugger to the `w3wp.exe` process to debug either of the two projects.

--- Ferda